# Windows 10 update stuck on separate installation

Tags: windows-10, updates

I recently upgraded my computer to Windows 10 and yesterday I got a notification saying that some updates required a separate installation to be completed.

However, when I click on the Install Now button nothing happens, the progrees circle keep spinning and the window get locked.

The list of updates includes the following items:

- Microsoft - Camera - Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000
- Microsoft - Pointing Drawing - Microsoft Hardware USB Mouse
- Microsoft - Keyboard - Microsoft Hardware USB Keyboard.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image: Update window with separate installation message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem

Turn off UAC and try again :)

Comment: Can you explain how this would help?

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure why it works...I think maybe UAC messed up with Windows Update. UAC is supposed to pop up some kind of warning when you are trying to install updates but somehow the popup is not able to show up, so the updates stuck and keep waiting for your confirmation. By disabling UAC, it no longer gonna get in the way so installation would not be interrupted.

Comment: It really worked! It looks like a bug, for some reason the UAC window was not being displayed, which prevented the driver installation from completing. When I set the UAC to "Never notify" the update was installed correctly.

Answer (score 5):

This is being caused by a glitch between User Access Control (UAC) and Windows Update (WU), where WU tries to load a UAC auth dialog within the WU window, even tho windows requires that UAC dialogs open up in protected mode (where the rest of your desktop greys out while UAC is waiting for a response). While you can disable UAC to get past it, this opens your PC up to risk, even if only disabled long enough to install the update. (What if you have some malware waiting in the wings for an opportunity to strike!?)

This is the safest and easiest way to get around the problem: After clicking the Install Now button, which locks up the WU window and optionally plays a chime sound, simply press Alt+Y on your keyboard. This will select "Yes" from the UAC window that is present, but not visible (due to it not loading in protected mode). Your WU window should now unlock and begin installing the updates.

If you press Alt+Y and nothing happens, click once in the locked WU window to ensure it is active, and press Alt+Y again.

Comment: This is the correct answer, alt Y while the windows update window has focus does the trick

Answer (score 1):

After encountering the same problem, I used the workaround of finding the current device software on the Microsoft site [here](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads) and installing it manually. That eliminated the separate installation message in Settings/Windows Update.

For some buggy reason the OK-to-update dialogue box associated with consent.exe, which runs after you click on **Install now** shown in the screen shot above, doesn't appear on screen. So the update never proceeds.

Comment: Did not work for me. There is no stand-alone Windows 10 driver download for a Wireless Intellimous Explorer 2. There is one for a Natural Keyboard 4000, but after installing it, Windows Update still wants to start a separate installation.